# What is the Version number for windows 10 ? ( BATCH FILE )

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
 set "windows="
VER | find  " 5.1." > nul && set windows=XP
VER | find  " 5.2." > nul && set windows=XP 64-Bit or Server 2003 or Server 2003 R2 
VER | find  " 6.0." > nul && set windows=Vista or server 2008
VER | find  " 6.1." > nul && set windows=Win7 or server 2008 R2
VER | find  " 6.2." > nul && set windows=Windows 8
VER | find  " 6.3." > nul && set windows=Server 2012 R2 or Windows 8.1
```

here you see 6.3 is windows 8.1
but what number is windows 10 ?
can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 RTM is 10.0.10240. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver_(command)

Answer (score 0):

According to this source:
http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/11/why-windows-10-isnt-version-6-any-more-and-why-it-will-probably-work/

It is apparently, version 10.0, although earlier builds reported being version 6.4